# ANTLR Grammar line 1:6 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting '.'

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I am playing with antlr4 grammar files, and I wanted to write my own [jsonpath](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html) grammar.

I've comeup with this:

```
grammar ObjectPath;

objectPath      : dnot;

dnot            : ROOT expr ('.' expr)
                | EOF
                ;

expr            : select #selectExpr
                | ID #idExpr
                ;

select          : ID '[]' #selectAll
                | ID '[' INT ']' #selectIndex
                | ID '[' INT (',' INT)* ']' #selectIndexes
                | ID '[' INT ':' INT ']' #selectRange
                | ID '[' INT ':]' #selectFrom
                | ID '[:' INT ']' #selectUntil
                | ID '[-' INT ':]' #selectLast
                | ID '[?(' query ')]' #selectQuery
                ;

query           : expr (AND|OR) expr # andOr
                | ALL # all
                | QPREF ID # prop
                | QPREF ID GT INT # gt
                | QPREF ID LT INT # lt
                | QPREF ID EQ INT # eq
                | QPREF ID GTE INT # gte
                | QPREF ID LTE INT # lte
                ;

/** Lexer **/
ROOT    : '$.' ;
QPREF   : '@.' ;
ID      : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
INT     : '0' | [1-9][0-9]* ;
AND     : '&&' ;
OR      : '||' ;
GT      : '>'  ;
LT      : '<'  ;
EQ      : '==' ;
GTE     : '>=' ;
LTE     : '<=' ;
ALL     : '*'  ;
```

After running this on a simple expression:

```
CharStream input = CharStreams.fromString("$.name");
ObjectPathLexer lexer = new ObjectPathLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

ObjectPathParser parser = new ObjectPathParser(tokens);
ParseTree parseTree = parser.dnot();
ObjectPathDefaultVisitor visitor = ...
System.out.println(visitor.visit(parseTree));
System.out.println(parseTree.toStringTree(parser));
```

The output is ok, meaning that the "name" is actually retrieved from the json, but there's a warning I cannot explain:

```
line 1:6 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting '.'
```

I've read that I need to explicitly have an EOF rule added to my starting one (`dnot`), but this doesn't seem to work.

Any idea what can I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input `$.name` cannot be parsed by your rule:

```
dnot            : ROOT expr ('.' expr)
                | EOF
                ;
```

`$.name` produces 2 tokens:

1. `ROOT`
2. `ID`

But your first alternative, `ROOT expr ('.' expr)`, expects 2 expressions separated by a `.`. Perhaps you meant to make the second expr optional, like this:

```
dnot            : ROOT expr ('.' expr)*
                | EOF
                ;
```

And the `EOF` is generally added at the end of your start rule, to force the parser to consume all tokens. As you did it now, the parser successfully parsed `ROOT expr`, but then failed to parse further, and produces the warning you saw (expecting '.').

Since `objectPath` seems to be your start rule, I think this is what you want to do:

```
objectPath      : dnot EOF;

dnot            : ROOT expr ('.' expr)?
                ;
```

Also, tokens like these `[]`, `'[?('`, etc look suspicious. I'm not really familiar with Object Path, but by glueing these chars to each other, input like this `[ ]` (`[` and `]` separated by a space) will not be matched by `[]`. So if `foo[ ]` is valid, I'd write it like this instead:

```
select          : ID '[' ']' #selectAll
                | ...
```

and skip spaces in the lexer:

```
SPACES : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```